# Meaning of "put in all the salt and pepper"

Tags: meaning, charles-dickens, great-expectations

From Chapter 48 of Charles Dickens's *Great Expectations*:

> “Mr. Jaggers was for her [Molly, Mr. Jaggers's maidservant],” pursued Wemmick, with a look full of meaning, “and worked the case in a way quite astonishing. It was a desperate case, and it was comparatively early days with him then, and he worked it to general admiration; in fact, it may almost be said to have made him. He worked it himself at the police-office, day after day for many days, contending against even a committal; and at the trial where he couldn’t work it himself, sat under counsel, and—every one knew—**put in all the salt and pepper**.

The [1933 OED](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.271834/page/n61/mode/2up) oddly does not mention 'salt and pepper' but does contain the following entry for

> **salt, *sb.*, 3.c.** That which gives life or pungency to discourse or written composition ; poignancy of expression ; pungent wit.

Mr. Jaggers is depicted as being quick to punish ill-applied usages of words and other such minute discrepancies with noticeable vehemence, so could 'put in all the salt and pepper' refer to his imparting a certain flamboyance to the legal proceedings?

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct.

Comment: "Yes, that is correct" is a valid answer for the answer-box, though some more backing would be preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the OED entry for salt, there is this entry for ‘pepper and salt’

> With reference to the pungency or biting quality of pepper: intensity (of feeling), spirit, vigour; ‘spice’.

To illustrate the usage the definition includes this quote from the 1887 New Orleans *Lantern*

> *But let me commence my assault on the offending ones and give them pepper and salt.*

So combining ‘That which gives life or pungency to discourse’ with ‘ intensity (of feeling), spirit, vigour; [and] ‘spice’.’ might reasonably be interpreted as ‘imparting a certain flamboyance’ and vigour to the proceedings in hand.